# jQuery JSON call to ASP .NET website succeeding in IE but not in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I'm fetching JSON from my ASP .NET website using the following jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/blah/default.aspx/GetTestData',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(output) {
      var viewModel = $.parseJSON(output.d);
      ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
```

});

And then using the Knockout library to update my UI. The server-side code in default.aspx to get the data is as follows.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetTestData()
{
    var viewModel = null; // Get viewModel data from elsewhere.
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(viewModel);
}
```

This works fine in IE but when I try in Chrome and Firefox the JSON does not get returned. My breakpoint server-side does get hit so the web method is being called, but something is happening when it comes back to the browser.

I think it might be related to setting content or MIME types at either the browser or webserver end but I've not had any luck yet, does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually avoid the serialization and parsing by having your Page Method just return your object.

So, it would look like:

```
[WebMethod]
public static ViewModel GetTestData()
{
    var viewModel = createOrGetMyViewModelObjectFromSomewhere();
    return viewModel;
}
```

On the JavaScript side, it would look like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/blah/default.aspx/GetTestData',
    data: "{}",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (output) {
        var viewModel = output.d;
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    }
});
```

So, you don't need to serialize it in .NET and you don't need to parse it on the client-side. It is all handled by the "plumbing" on both sides.  Also, passing `data: "{}"` is important (or if you need parameters, they would go here).

Also, if you were calling a web service instead of Page Method, then you need to decorate the class with a `[ScriptService]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove the contentType param?

Comment: I've tried that, it breaks in IE as well then. The webserver returns all the markup for the default.aspx page instead of returning the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try putting empty **data** parameter above dataType: 'json',
like following

```
    data: "{}",
dataType: 'json',
```

that will do a trick!!

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand clearly. If you can't parse JSON string try this magic code:

```
var viewModel = eval('(' + data + ')');
```

where `data` is your response from server.